# Getting record counts with Entity Framework results in high number of reads

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

SQL Server 2016, Entity Framework 6.4 on .NET 4.6.2

Given these two tables:

- ParentTable (int masterId, int id)
- ChildTable (int id, bit isActive)

There's a one-to-many relationship between the `ParentTable` and the `ChildTable` on the `id` column.

I'd like to get a count of how many "active" child rows there are, with a masterId of 1. Simple enough in T-SQL

```
select count(1) 
from parentTable 
join childTable on parentTable.id = childTable.id
where masterId = 1 and isActive = 0
```

Now I'd like to do that in Entity Framework. Again, the syntax is simple enough:

```
 var activeCount= db.childTable.Count(d => d.parentTable.masterId == 1 && !d.isActive);
```

Both return the same count, however.... this Entity Framework call makes some ugly SQL which is REALLY inefficient:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[childTable] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[parentTable] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[id] = [Extent2].[id]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[masterId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[isActive] <> 1)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

The difference is 10 logical reads for the simple `count(1)` statement, and 9200 logical reads for the Entity Framework statement. I've messed around with different syntaxes for the EF and at this point they have all created the same T-SQL.

Am I missing something in EF to do this simple count efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three queries are asking for different things.

The first query doesn't include the condition that `childTable.isActive = 1`.

The LINQ expression does include that condition. This is the only query that seems to match the intent you stated, "get a count of how many "active" child rows there are, with a masterId of 1".

The generated SQL has the *opposite* condition for isActive: `[Extent1].[isActive] <> 1`. It also seems to be looking for a different `masterid`.

While Linq to SQL can definitely produce some terrible SQL, that's not the problem here. The generated sql is only ugly in the sense that it uses verbose aliases and ugly parameter names. But the inequality along with the different `masterid` is the issue.

Double check your code against your intent and make sure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: I've fixed the typos in my question. Sorry, happened when trying to convert my specific table names and ID names to a generic question. But the question and problem stands.

Comment: Do you want the active rows, or the inactive rows? In the question text you have "I'd like to get a count of how many "active" child rows there are", but all of the queries now seem to be asking for the inactive rows. If you do want the inactive, you could try `&& d.isActive == false` in the LINQ. This will turn the generated inequality comparison into an equality comparison.

Comment: d.isActive == false and !d.isActive is the same thing.

Comment: It's the same thing logically. it's not the same thing in terms of transliteration. `!isActive` is being transliterated to `isActive <> 1`. But `isActive == false` will be transliterated to `isActive = 0`. There's a big difference in sql between an equality predicate, and an inequality predicate.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty amazing and I learned something new, and led me to the actual solution. I didn't realize that my "isActive" flag was nullable in the db, so when EF created isActive<>1, it caused far more reads. 

Once I removed the nullable, both IsActive<>1 and IsActive=0 produced the same performance since this is a bit column. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, nullable bits sure are fun. I suppose they are needed sometimes (I agree with Codd, not Date, on nulls in relations), but I just instinctively hate nullable bits.